# Write a transposition as a product of adjacent transpositions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations

I just read that any transposition can be written as a product of adjacent transpositions. I thought that I knew the right proof of this, but then I read that $\tau_{i,j} = \tau_{i,i-1} \circ...\circ \tau_{j+1,j},$ where $i > j$ and $\tau_{a,b}$ permutes the a-th and b-th element.

Somehow I don't think that this is true or is it?

Comment: is: *Write a permutation as a product of adjacent transpositions*?

Comment: ok, with an example: is it something like: $(123)=(13)(12)$?

Comment: This is not true.  For instance, $(42) \neq (43)(32)$.  Plug in $2$ (on either side) and you do get $4$, but if you plug in $4$ on the left hand side you get $3$.

Comment: this question asks if: $(ij) = (i \quad i-1)...(j+1 \quad j)$ holds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I go about solving something like this is by drawing a bunch of $x$'s to denote generic numbers and $o$'s to denote the numbers I want to transpose in a line.  Then the game is to only be allowed to do adjacent transpositions if to achieve your desired affect.  Your first goal is to get your first $o$ to where the second $o$ is, and you can do that by what you have written.  After playing around like this you can convince yourself that the formula should be:

$$ (i\, j) = (j+1\,\,\,j)\dots(i-1\,\,\,i-2)(i\,\,\,i-1)(i-1\,\,\,i-2)\dots(j+1\,\,\,j).$$

Now you just have to prove this formula is correct.

Comment: with this recipe, how do you factorize $(1,5)$?

Comment: @janmarqz Good question, I should have provided an example to clarify.  $(1,5) = (2,1)(3,2)(4,3)(5,4)(4,3)(3,2)(2,1)$.  Check it out, it works!

Comment: please write it for $(1,3)$

Comment: :) $(1,3) = (2,1)(3,2)(2,1)$.

Comment: Hehehhe, I recognized! It is the conjugation class! Thanks.

Comment: janmarqz, good observation!  I didnt recognize that, but this is indeed nothing more than conjugating a single transposition.

Comment: BTW, this is similar to what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Properties says.