# order of transpositions making up a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

If I understood correctly, any permutation can be written as a sequence $s$ ("product") of distinct transpositions (2-element swaps, each swap occurs at most once in the sequence (I consider 2 swaps equal if they swap the elements at the same positions, no matter which elements occupy the position at that time in the sequence)).
For example, consider the permutation $(3,4,2,1)$ which can be obtained by swapping positions $(1,4)$, $(2,3)$, and then $(1,2)$ (at that point positions 1 and 2 are occupied by elements 4 and 3).

Now, I'm very uncertain about the degree to which I can reorder the transpositions without changing the resulting permutation. For example $(3,4,2,1)$ can also be obtained by swapping $(2,3), (1,4),(1,2)$, but not by $(1,2),(1,4),(2,3)$.

In particular, I want to assume without loss of generality that, for any given permutation, there is a sequence $s$ of transpositions such that the following transposition $(i,j)$ is last in $s$: here, $j$ is the maximum element and $i$ is the maximum over all elements occuring with $j$ in a transposition in $s$.

Can I assume this without loss of generality and what should I cite to support this? Can I assume other properties about the sequence (for example, could all transpositions be of the form $(1,j)$ while maintaining the property that none of them is repeated)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any permutation breaks down into disjoint cycles.  For example $(3,1,2,5,4)$ is the composition of cycles $(123)(45)$.  The cycles can be performed in any order and we will get the same permutation.

Further each cycle can be broken down into a product of transpositions of the form $(a_ka_{k-1})(a_{k-1}a_{k-2})\cdots (a_2a_1)$, with the $a_i$ distinct.  For example: $$(12345)=(54)(43)(32)(21).$$  Given a cycle, we can label any of its elements $a_1$, so we can get the final transposition $(a_2a_1)$ in the factorisation to be any transposition of consecutive elements in the cycle.

Thus given a permutation, you can express it as a product of transpositions, with the final transposition being any transposition of consecutive elements in a cycle that you want.

Note that this factorisation into transpositions does not use any transposition more than once.

We have $$(ij)=(1i)(1j)(1i),$$ so any permutation can be expressed as a product of $(1i)$.  However it may that you need to use the same transposition more than once.  For example the permutation $(1,3,2)$ is not equal to $(12)(13)$ or $(13)(12)$.

Comment: "Note we can cycle the order of these transpositions around, and still get the same cycle." - this is interesting. But (12)(14)(23) = (4312) and (14)(23)(12) = (3421) but (12)(14)(23) is just a cyclic shift of (14)(23)(12), no? Maybe  I misunderstood something...

Comment: The key word was "these", but I should edit to make this clearer.  I was referring specifically to products of the form $(a_ka_{k-1})(a_{k-1}a_{k-2})\cdots (a_2a_1)$ with the $a_i$ distinct.  Now edited.  Does it make sense now?

Comment: Cycles commute iff they are disjoint.

Comment: I think I got it now, thanks! One last thing, is this cyclic shifting equivalence of this particular representation folklore in algebra? That is, do I just cite any introductional monograph for this or is there a particular paper that proves it?

Comment: I think you just say it holds by symmetry: The cycle $(a_1a_2\cdots a_k)$ is invariant under cycling round the $a_i$, so you can cycle round the $a_i$ in the factorisation $(a_ka_{k-1})(a_{k-1}a_{k-2})\cdots (a_2a_1)$ which is the same as cycling round the transpositions.

Comment: IMHO we should do the following correction: 1. By cycle definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Definitio, (123)(45) should be (132)(45). 2. Maybe you want to say "you can put any *cycle* you like last" which corresponds to "give you the *last cycle*"

Comment: Here are some clarification: 1. "Note (in the case of products as above" may mean $(a_ka_{k-1})(a_{k-1}a_{k-2})\cdots (a_2a_1)$ can be written as $(a_2a_1)(a_3 a_2)\cdots (a_{k-1}a_{k-2})(a_ka_{k-1})$. This is shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Properties and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3420633/1059606 (Notice we should execute the right factor first as wikipedia says). 2. "does not use any transposition *more than once*" is due to permutation is decomposed into one or more *disjoint* cycles.